# Animate Chip checking in Material Chipgroup (Android)

Tags: java, android, android-studio, kotlin, material-design

I'm writing an Android app where a user has to select an option using a `ChipGroup` and `Chips`.
Everything is working fine, it's just a bit clunky as there is no animation except the default ripple when selecting a `Chip`.

I've read [the Material Design 3 Docs](https://m3.material.io/components/chips/overview) and **found [this video](https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/design-spec/o/projects%2Fm3%2Fimages%2Fkzeduuwe-hero_single-select_3P.mp4?alt=media&token=b9b421ed-c64f-4217-9908-66bb66b86304) showing a nice animation that I'd like to implement**, but I don't know how.

I've tried:

1. enabling

   ```
   android:animateLayoutChanges="true"
   ```

   but that only animates the adding and removing of a `Chip`, not the checking and unchecking.
2. using

   ```
   TransitionManager.beginDelayedTransition(chipGroup);
   ```

   and that works fine on the chipGroup but the content of the `Chip` (tick appearing and text rescaling) does not animate.

---

Please tell me if I'm doing something wrong, here is also the method I use to add and select those `Chips`:

```
ChipAdapter adapter = new ChipAdapter(getContext());

    for(int i = 0; i < adapter.getCount(); i++){
        View chip = adapter.getView(i, chipGroup, chipGroup);
        if(chip instanceof Chip) {
            chip.setId(i);
            chip.setOnClickListener(v -> {
                for(int p = 0; p < chipGroup.getChildCount(); p++){
                    chipGroup.getChildAt(p).setSelected(false);
                }
                chip.setSelected(true);
            });
            chipGroup.addView(chip);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Update:** Appended Jetpack Compose answer.

## With XML

So as far as I can tell there is no embed way to simply enable this animation, but I found two ways to **mimic the animation** shown in your linked video.

## Results

#### Option 1

[image: Gif showing the result of option 1]

#### Option 2

[image: Gif showing the result of option 2]

## Code & Explaination

### Option 1

This option works by **enabling the `animateLayoutChanges` option** of the ChipGroup that contains your chips

```
android:animateLayoutChanges="true"
```

and adding the following code for your `ChipGroup`:

```
for (view in chipGroup.children) {
    val chip = view as Chip
    chip.setOnCheckedChangeListener { buttonView, _ ->
        val index = chipGroup.indexOfChild(buttonView)
        chipGroup.removeView(buttonView)
        chipGroup.addView(buttonView, index)
    }
}
```

This code will automatically **remove the chip and instantly add it back** to the ChipGroup whenever the selection state of a chip changes.

##### Drawbacks

- The animation is rather a transition of the form *stateBefore -> invisible -> stateAfter* than *stateBefore -> stateAfter* what results in the chip **"flashing"**.

---

### Option 2

For this option add the following **custom Chip class (*Kotlin*)** to your project and change your chips to be instances of `CheckAnimationChip` instead of `com.google.android.material.chip.Chip`:

```
import android.animation.ObjectAnimator
import android.content.Context
import android.util.AttributeSet
import androidx.core.animation.doOnEnd
import com.google.android.material.chip.Chip
import com.google.android.material.chip.ChipDrawable

private const val CHIP_ICON_SIZE_PROPERTY_NAME = "chipIconSize"

// A value of '0f' would be interpreted as 'use the default size' by the ChipDrawable, so use a slightly larger value.
private const val INVISIBLE_CHIP_ICON_SIZE = 0.00001f

/**
 * Custom Chip class which will animate transition between the [isChecked] states.
 */
class CheckAnimationChip @JvmOverloads constructor(
    context: Context,
    attrs: AttributeSet? = null,
    defStyleAttr: Int = com.google.android.material.R.attr.chipStyle
) : Chip(context, attrs, defStyleAttr) {

    private var onCheckedChangeListener: OnCheckedChangeListener? = null
    private var _chipDrawable: ChipDrawable
    private var defaultCheckedIconSize: Float
    private var currentlyScalingDown = false

    var animationDuration = 200L

    init {
        // Set default values for this category of chip.
        isCheckable = true
        isCheckedIconVisible = true

        _chipDrawable = chipDrawable as ChipDrawable
        defaultCheckedIconSize = _chipDrawable.chipIconSize

        super.setOnCheckedChangeListener { buttonView, isChecked ->
            if (currentlyScalingDown) {
                // Block the changes caused by the scaling-down animation.
                return@setOnCheckedChangeListener
            }
            onCheckedChangeListener?.onCheckedChanged(buttonView, isChecked)

            if (isChecked) {
                scaleCheckedIconUp()
            } else if (!isChecked) {
                scaleCheckedIconDown()
            }
        }
    }

    /**
     * Scale the size of the Checked-Icon from invisible to its default size.
     */
    private fun scaleCheckedIconUp() {
        ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(_chipDrawable, CHIP_ICON_SIZE_PROPERTY_NAME,
            INVISIBLE_CHIP_ICON_SIZE, defaultCheckedIconSize)
            .apply {
                duration =  animationDuration
                start()
                doOnEnd {
                    _chipDrawable.chipIconSize = defaultCheckedIconSize
                }
            }
    }

    /**
     * Scale the size of the Checked-Icon from its default size down to invisible. To achieve this, the
     * [isChecked] property needs to be manipulated. It is set to be true till the animation has ended.
     */
    private fun scaleCheckedIconDown() {
        currentlyScalingDown = true
        isChecked = true
        ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(_chipDrawable, CHIP_ICON_SIZE_PROPERTY_NAME,
            defaultCheckedIconSize, INVISIBLE_CHIP_ICON_SIZE)
            .apply {
                duration =  animationDuration
                start()
                doOnEnd {
                    isChecked = false
                    currentlyScalingDown = false
                    _chipDrawable.chipIconSize = defaultCheckedIconSize
                }
            }
    }

    override fun setOnCheckedChangeListener(listener: OnCheckedChangeListener?) {
        onCheckedChangeListener = listener
    }
}
```

This class **changes the size of the chip's icon** by using an `ObjectAnimator`. Therefore it accesses the `ChipDrawable` of the chip and changes the `chipIconSize` property with the animator.

##### Drawbacks (rather picky)

- This will only animate the icon size and not a complete transition between the drawables of the chip like in the linked video (e.g. there is **no smooth transition of the border or background** in this implementation).
- You can observe a **flickering of adjacent chips** during the animation (see chip "Last 4 Weeks" in the gif), however I could only observe this problem on the emulator and did **not** notice it **on a physical device**.

---

## Jetpack Compose

In Jetpack Compose you can make use of the `animateConentSize()` Modifier:

```
FilterChip(
    selected = selected,
    onClick = { /* Handle Click */ },
    leadingIcon = {
        Box(
            Modifier.animateContentSize(keyframes { durationMillis = 200 })
        ) {
            if (selected) {
                Icon(
                    imageVector = Icons.Default.Done,
                    contentDescription = null,
                    modifier = Modifier.size(FilterChipDefaults.IconSize)
                )
            }
        }
    },
    label = { /* Text */ }
)
```

The important part here is to always have a composable (here the `Box`) for the `leadingIcon` that holds the check-icon if the chip is selected and is empty if not. This composable can then be animated smoothly with the `animateContentSize()` modifier.